# Custom .ttf fonts to use in C# windows.Form

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

How do I use a custom .tff font file I have with my current windows.forms application? 
I read some where that I use it as an embedded resource, but how do I set it the System.Drawing.Font type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This article: [How to embed a true type font](https://web.archive.org/web/20141224204810/http://bobpowell.net/embedfonts.aspx) shows how to do what you ask in .NET.

**How to embed a True Type font**

> Some applications, for reasons of esthetics or a required visual
> style, will embed certain uncommon fonts so that they are always there
> when needed regardless of whether the font is actually installed on
> the destination system.
>
> The secret to this is twofold. First the font needs to be placed in
> the resources by adding it to the solution and marking it as an
> embedded resource. Secondly, at runtime, the font is loaded via a
> stream and stored in a PrivateFontCollection object for later use.
>
> This example uses a font which is unlikely to be installed on your
> system. Alpha Dance is a free True Type font that is available from
> the Free Fonts Collection. This font was embedded into the application
> by adding it to the solution and selecting the "embedded resource"
> build action in the properties.

[image: Figure 1. The Alpha Dance font file embedded in the solution.]

> Once the file has been successfully included in the resources you need
> to provide a PrivateFontCollection object in which to store it and a
> method by which it's loaded into the collection. The best place to do
> this is probably the form load override or event handler. The
> following listing shows the process. Note how the AddMemoryFont method
> is used. It requires a pointer to the memory in which the font is
> saved as an array of bytes. In C# we can use the unsafe keyword for
> convienience but VB must use the capabilities of the Marshal classes
> unmanaged memory handling. The latter option is of course open to C#
> programmers who just don't like the unsafe keyword.
> PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Stream fontStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("embedfont.Alphd___.ttf");

  byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
  fontStream.Read(fontdata,0,(int)fontStream.Length);
  fontStream.Close();
  unsafe
  {
    fixed(byte * pFontData = fontdata)
    {
      pfc.AddMemoryFont((System.IntPtr)pFontData,fontdata.Length);
    }
  }
}
```

> Fonts may have only certain styles which are available and
> unfortunately, selecting a font style that doesn't exist will throw an
> exception. To overcome this the font can be interrogated to see which
> styles are available and only those provided by the font can be used.
> The following listing demonstrates how the Alpha Dance font is used by
> checking the available font styles and showing all those that exist.
> Note that the underline and strikethrough styles are pseudo styles
> constructed by the font rendering engine and are not actually provided
> in glyph form.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
  bool bold=false;
  bool regular=false;
  bool italic=false;

  e.Graphics.PageUnit=GraphicsUnit.Point;
  SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

  float y=5;

  System.Drawing.Font fn;

  foreach(FontFamily ff in pfc.Families)
  {
    if(ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
    {
      regular=true;
      fn=new Font(ff,18,FontStyle.Regular);
      e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name,fn,b,5,y,StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
      fn.Dispose();
      y+=20;
    }
    if(ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Bold))
    {
      bold=true;
      fn=new Font(ff,18,FontStyle.Bold);
      e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name,fn,b,5,y,StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
      fn.Dispose();
      y+=20;
    }
    if(ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Italic))
    {
      italic=true;
      fn=new Font(ff,18,FontStyle.Italic);
      e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name,fn,b,5,y,StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
      fn.Dispose();
      y+=20;
    }
    if(bold  && italic)
    {
      fn=new Font(ff,18,FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
      e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name,fn,b,5,y,StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
      fn.Dispose();
      y+=20;
    }
    fn=new Font(ff,18,FontStyle.Underline);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name,fn,b,5,y,StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    fn.Dispose();
    y+=20;
    fn=new Font(ff,18,FontStyle.Strikeout);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name,fn,b,5,y,StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    fn.Dispose();
  }

  b.Dispose();
}
```

> Figure 2 shows the application in action.

[image: Figure 2. The embedded Alpha Dance font.]

See the Form1_Paint event handler, it shows specifically how to set the System.Drawing.Font type.  It is based on using the System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [AddFontResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183327(VS.85).aspx) API function through p/invoke, passing FR_PRIVATE to prevent installing a global font. Then you should be able to pass the font name to the Font constructor as usual.

Edit: If you use the [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) and load the font from an external file, you don't even need this. If you load the font from an embedded resource, use Ash's solution.

Comment: Is there an example some where? I can really understand the MSDN link. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 3):

You might find useful a MSDN article [How to: Create a Private Font Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw.aspx).